# Yii ActiveRecord-Relation save not connecting models

Tags: yii

I have a problem with Yii's activerecord-relation-behavior extension.

I have a main model: `User` and a sub-model: `UserPerson` (kind of profile)

The relation between these two model is setted, the models behavior is using yiiext, but I still can not connect them.

In this context `$this` is a model, that extends the `User` model and called `RegistrationModel`

```
$person = new \UserPerson();
$person->full_name = $this->name;
$person->birthday = $this->birthday;
$person->gender = $this->gender;

$this->person = $person;
$this->person->save();
```

In this way, I should be able to run: `$this->save()`
But I get this error:

> You can not save a record that has new related records!

I tried a lot of variations, but only the ugly, relationless version worked. :(

```
$person->user_id = $this->id;
//..
$person->save();
```

Does anyone have a suggestion to this problem?

Comment: That's how it's supposed to work. Yii does not support auto-save of related records. You have to save them manually.

Comment: But that's why I use [activerecord-relation-behavior](https://github.com/yiiext/activerecord-relation-behavior), to get this work like this and have real relations between models.

Comment: Oh, sorry, missed that you mentioned that extension.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is in the [repository of the extension](https://github.com/yiiext/activerecord-relation-behavior):

> **"You can not save a record that has new related records!"**
>
> You have assigned a record to a relation which has not been saved (it
>   is not in the database yet). Since ActiveRecord Relation Behavior
>   needs its primary key to save it to a relation table, this will not
>   work. You have to call ->save() on all new records before saving the
>   related record.

So you have to save the related model, add the related elements and then save the model.

```
$person = new \UserPerson();
$person->full_name = $this->name;
$person->birthday = $this->birthday;
$person->gender = $this->gender;
$person->save();
//now $person has a primary key

$this->person = $person;
$this->person->save();
```

Comment: In this case, `$person` must be valid and savable.
I get a `foreign key constraint fail` when I try to save `$person` without user's id. (`$this`) 
So anyway, I have to give the user id to the `$person` ? Not this is what this **activerecord-relation-behavior** should care about?

Comment: No the id is given by the sql database when you save the model, but you id field needs to be with the auto-increment property!

Comment: Sorry, than maybe I can't explain myself. I have a `User` and a `UserPerson` class, and the `UserPerson` belongs to a `User`, with a foreign key. (`UserPerson.user_id`)
Btw.: I'm using PHP generated GUID for every `id` field, not auto-incremented value.

Comment: The stuff is User needs `UserPerson` id's to save the relation (it's logic since this is the id that makes the relation) so you need to assign an id to your `UserPerson` model. In general the id is assigned by mysql when saving the model, and then with the **activerecord-relation-behavior** you will be able to save the relation. But since you use the PHP GUID I think you'll need to assign the id to your `UserPerson` Model manually.

Comment: I have the relation set in User `'person' => array(self::HAS_ONE, 'UserPerson', 'user_id'),` and vice-versa .
So you think The problem is in the type of id? That would be weird :)

Comment: I found the solution! Instead of this: `$this->person = $person;` I have to give the id and not the UserProfile model. so: `$this->user_id = $person->id;`